# Classe Pai com a mesma responsabilidade da classe filha

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho minha classe Item

```
public class Item
{
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public decimal Valor {get;set;}

   public ICollection<SubItem> SubItens {get;set;}
}

public class SubItem 
{
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public decimal Valor {get;set;}
}
```

Tenho essas duas classes

O que acontece é que, quando eu tenho `SubItens`, o valor da classe `Item` devem ser anulados, mas quando eu não tenho `subitens` o valor da classe `Item` é o valor válido.

Pois bem, é meio confuso, porém na minha regra de negócio é necessário uma implementação com base nessa.

Minha dúvida é, é correto ter isso ? Qual seria a melhor forma de eu deixar isso mais fácil ? Usando Herança ?

Comment: A classe `Item` vai ter metodos? Ou so' dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode simplificar pra uma classe só:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? ItemPaiId { get; set; }

    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public decimal Valor {get;set;}

    public virtual Item ItemPai { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> SubItens {get;set;}
}
```

Creio que resolve todo o problema.

Comment: e se a classe Item tiver mais propriedades a qual algum Item de subitens não precisará ? ficará com valores nulos ?

Comment: Pode ser, ou então você usa herança, mas a herança a meu ver é um complicador neste caso.

Comment: Por que complicado ?

Comment: Cigano, e me tira uma dúvida, essa "ideia" que passei não fere a ideia que uma classe deve ter apenas uma responsabilidade?

Comment: @Rod A responsabilidade de cada classe de dados é representar um registro em uma coleção, que chamamos de entidade. Quanto a isso não vejo nada de errado.

Answer (score 8):

Não sei qual é o propósito da *classe* mas, partindo apenas do seu código, penso que isto é o suficiente:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public decimal Valor {get;set;}

   public ICollection<Item> SubItens {get;set;}
}
```

Não há necessidade de uma classe ***SubItem*** porque um ***SubItem*** não é mais do que um ***item***.
Conclusão que você já tirou quando admitiu que ***Item*** e ***SubItem*** têm a mesma responsabilidade

Comment: Tendo como base a estrutura das entidade, eu concordo com esta modelagem, porém ele pode ter simplificado as entidades para dá foco ao problema apresentando, desta forma Item e SubItem podem ser diferentes. Em todo caso, isto não responde a pergunta, como inorar o valor da Classe Pai se ela tiver Filhos.

Answer (score 0):

Da maneira que a classe `Item` está estruturada, mesmo aplicando a solução do @ramaral, vai ser muito difícil para o cliente usar a arvore de itens.
O cliente vai sempre ter de verificar se um item é um nó na árvore (`if(item.SubItems != null)`) ou se o item é uma folha da árvore.

Por exemplo, para imprimir a árvore inteira, o cliente teria de definir um método recursivo, e a cada iteração determinar o tipo de item.

```
public void PrintNode(Item item)
{
    if(item.SubItems == null)               //é folha?
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    else                                    //é nó?
        foreach(var subItem in item.SubItems)
            PrintNode(subItem);
}

Item root = //criar a arvore
PrintNode(root);
```

O ideal seria reestruturar a classe `Item` de modo a expor apenas métodos de manipulação, e aplicar o padrão [Composite](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html), de modo a tratar todos os items, sejam nós ou folhas, uniformemente.

```
public interface IItem
{
    void Do(Action<Item> action);
}

public class ItemComposite : IItem
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IItem> _subItems;

    public ItemComposite(IEnumerable<IItem> subItems)
    {
        _subItems = subItems;
    }

    public void Do(Action<Item> action)
    {
        foreach(var subItem in _subItems)
            subItem.Do(action);
    }
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    public string Nome {get; private set;}
    public decimal Valor {get; private set;}

    public Item(string nome, decimal valor)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Valor = valor;
    }

    public void Do(Action<Item> action)
    {
        action(this);
    }
}
```

Codigo do cliente para imprimir a árvore:

```
IItem root = //construir árvore 
root.Do(item => Console.WriteLine(item.Nome));
```

Outra possível  implementação com suporte para `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public interface IItem : IEnumerable<Item>
{
}

public class ItemComposite : IItem
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IItem> _subItems;

    public ItemComposite(IEnumerable<IItem> subItems)
    {
        _subItems = subItems;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _subItems.SelectMany(subItem => subItem).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; private set; }

    public Item(string nome, decimal valor)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Valor = valor;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Codigo do cliente

```
IItem root = //...

foreach(Item item in root)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Nome);
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode colocar uma pequena logica no `get` do `Valor` do `Item`.

No exemplo abaixo, caso o objeto `Item`, possua algum `SubItem`, a propriedade `Valor` do `Item` irá retornar o somatório das propriedades `Valor` dos seus `SubItem`

```
public class Item
{
    private decimal valor;
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public decimal Valor 
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.SubItens != null && SubItens.Any())
                return this.SubItens.Select(subItem => subItem.Valor).Sum();
            return this.valor;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valor = value;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<SubItem> SubItens {get;set;}
}

public class SubItem 
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public decimal Valor {get;set;}
}
```